xv6 uartinit: set baud rate
I'm confused about how the baud rate 38.4K is calculated in xv6.
Here is the UART documentation.
void
uartinit(void)
{
  // disable interrupts.
  WriteReg(IER, 0x00);

  // special mode to set baud rate.
  WriteReg(LCR, LCR_BAUD_LATCH);

  // LSB for baud rate of 38.4K.
  WriteReg(0, 0x03);

  // MSB for baud rate of 38.4K.
  WriteReg(1, 0x00);

  // leave set-baud mode,
  // and set word length to 8 bits, no parity.
  WriteReg(LCR, LCR_EIGHT_BITS);

  // reset and enable FIFOs.
  WriteReg(FCR, FCR_FIFO_ENABLE | FCR_FIFO_CLEAR);

  // enable transmit and receive interrupts.
  WriteReg(IER, IER_TX_ENABLE | IER_RX_ENABLE);

  initlock(&uart_tx_lock, "uart");
}

I think these lines in the above documentation may illustrate baud rate settings:

PROGRAMMABLE BAUD RATE GENERATOR: The 16550 contains a programmable Baud Rate Generator that is capable of tracking any clock input from DC-8 MHz and dividing it by any divisor from 1 to 2^16-1. The output frequency of the Baudout is equal to the 16X of transmission baud rate (Baudout=16 X Baud Rate). Customize Baud Rates can be achieved by selecting proper divisor values for MSB and LSB of baud rate generator.


I also found Qemu UART documentation. On page 15, it said that if the Cystal is 1.8432 MHz, and Decimal Divisor for 16x clock is 3, then you'll get 38.4k baud rate. But how to get 1.8432 MHz in xv6? Is it a minimum requirement?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Have you tried to read datasheet for that platform? Do your homework first, it may be that you don't need to ask after all.

xv6 targets standard x86 PC hardware, and on a PC, the 16550 UART is connected to a clock source with frequency 1.8432 MHz.  This has been true ever since the original IBM PC released in 1981 (with an 8250 UART); see page 2-135 of its Technical Reference Manual.
The divisor in that code is set to 3, so the output frequency is 1.8432 / 3 = 0.6144 MHz, or 614.4 KHz.  The baud rate is 1/16 of that, which is indeed 38.4K.
